# How to add conditional formatting (or colors) to a table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, formatting, conditional-statements, matlab-table

How can I add conditional formatting (e.g. the background or text changed to a color) of my Matlab table with numbers.

I have figured already figured out how to format the numerical values of my table:

```
T = table;
T.field = rand(5,1)
t = T.field;

m = t ./ divNumber;
c = num2cell(m);

fun = @(x) sprintf(formatStr, x);
d = cellfun(fun, c, 'UniformOutput',0);

d(strcmp(d,'NaN')) = {''};

T.field = d
```

Comment: Have you looked at using the report generator: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/create-and-format-tables_buid8hn.html#bulak82

Comment: Seems like the solution indeed, but I do not have the resources to purchase this toolbox..........

Comment: I guess you could use markup: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btga6k2-1 but you'd have to write some ugly logic for the conditional formatting (unless you can somehow include CSS)

Comment: My idea is to use it with the publishing to a html. But indeed it would be best not to write so much ugly logic. Matlab tables do not support any colors??

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs about formatting them: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-table.html I guess html makes more sense for fancy display than matlab. You could try latex instead, also check the file exchange to see if someone has already written the code for you. Otherwise, copy the table into Excel?

Comment: Yeah its also what I find.. but I wanted to limit use of external software and just print out a formatted report automatically every day... I am really surprised and dissapointed that its so hard to add just plain color to a table cell

Comment: Well it's not really what MATLAB is for. If you have Excel, I think your best solution is to make an empty template in Excel (has all the formatting but no data) and then just copy the template use xlswrite to add the data each day. Then you'll have a formatted report. You can even write a vba macro (or just copy jan debruin's) to copy your excel sheet and email it as formatted html.